# Make function use an object as its scope

Tags: javascript, object, scope

Say I have code like this:

```
var opts = {hello: "it's me", imusthavetried: "a thousand times"}
function myFunction (options) {
}
myFunction(opts)
```

Is there any way to make it so `myFunction` can just write `hello` instead of `options.hello`? I know I could loop through each of the option object children and redefine them, but is there any way to automatically use the options object as a function's scope?

Comment: what do you mean by "can just write hello instead of options.hello" ?

Comment: `with(options) {alert(hello);}`

Comment: Do you mean inside `myFunction`  to do `console.log(options['hello'])`? This should log `'its me'`

Comment: @VincentNguyen no, @NiettheDarkAbsol answered my question. I mean you can just do `console.log(hello)` without writing `options` at all or explicitly assigning a value to `hello`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol but if `hello` was defined externally, it would return that value, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) block, but its use is generally frowned upon (as explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Ambiguity_contra)). It used to be that it would cause performance issues, but that has been fixed in modern versions of the V8 engine (the engine used by Google Chrome and Node.js).

```js
function myFunction(options) {
  with(options) {
    console.log(hello);
  }
}

myFunction({ hello: 'Hello, World!' });
```

Comment: is it disabled in "use: strict"? Also, if `hello` was defined externally, wouldn't it use `hello` instead of `options.hello`?

Comment: @BenGubler Yes, it's disabled in strict mode. And no, it always prefers to use `options.hello`.

Comment: Is there any equivalent that works with strict mode?

Comment: @BenGubler There's no equivalent in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
var opts = {hello: "it's me", imusthavetried: "a thousand times"}
function myFunction (options) {
    with( options ) {
        console.log( hello ); // "it's me"
    }
}
myFunction(opts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to bind the "this" object to your object:

```js
var opts = {hello: "it's me", imusthavetried: "a thousand times"}
function myFunction (options) {
  console.log(this.hello)
}

myFunction = myFunction.bind(opts);
myFunction();
```